# How can I show teammates health for Soldier:76?

Tags: overwatch

I've been told that somewhere, there is an option specific to Soldier 76 (and a few other specific classes) that allow you to see teammates health. For characters like Mercy it is enabled by default, but for Soldier 76 you have to enable it.

I can't figure out where to go to do that though.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you go into the options menu, you'll see the option to toggle teammate health. Note that Zarya also has this option as well; the exact instructions that follow are the same except to pick Zarya from the All Heroes dropdown menu.

As of an older update Blizzard made it able to enable this option across all heroes.

You'll need to go to:

- **Options** menu from the main menu
- **Controls** on the top bar of the Options menu
- Select **Soldier 76** from the All Heroes dropdown menu

The option is labelled "Allied Health Bars".  Toggle On to show.

[image]

Comment: Any clue why this is Soilder 76 only?

Comment: @DavidGrinberg Because he has a heal, and can heal others, but is not a support character primarily. Useful to know when to throw down Biotic Field.

Comment: @DavidGrinberg This is not limited to Soldier 76. This option is also available for Zarya as her ability allows her to shield teammates; she as well does have a Toggle Teammate Health option

Comment: +1, I'm definitely doing that. Hopefully I can just choose to show health regardless of which hero I'm using.